# How can I make this query work in D7?

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to rewrite this database query from the line 52 of my template.php D6 site

```
  $uid = db_query('SELECT pm.author FROM {pm_message} pm INNER JOIN {pm_index} pmi ON pmi.mid = pm.mid AND pmi.thread_id = %d WHERE pm.author <> %d ORDER BY pm.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1', $thread['thread_id'], $user->uid);
```

into D7 standards.

But it keeps giving me

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to db_query() must be an
>   array, string given, called in
>   C:\wamp2\www\site-name\sites\all\themes\simpler\template.php on line
>   52 and defined in db_query() (line 2313 of
>   C:\wamp2\www\site-name\includes\database\database.inc).

This DB query is part of a template.php snippet that shows user pictures in Private Messages module, and makes it look like Facebook or other social networking site.  You can see the full snippet here.  Because Private Messages has a unified value $participants (or the message thread) this DB query is basically trying to isolate the last author except the current user.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 6):

As the error message says: 'Argument 2 passed to db_query() must be an array ...'.

Drupal 7 switched the database layer to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), so placeholder replacement in [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) changed a bit - try:

```
$query = 'SELECT pm.author FROM {pm_message} pm'
  . ' INNER JOIN {pm_index} pmi ON pmi.mid = pm.mid AND pmi.thread_id = :thread_id'
  . ' WHERE pm.author <> :uid'
  . ' ORDER BY pm.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1';
$args = array(
  ':thread_id' => $thread['thread_id'],
  ':uid' => $user->uid,
);
$uid = db_query($query, $args)->fetchField();
```

Splitted and reformatted for readability. Untested, so beware of typos.

Note the [`->fetchField()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3AfetchField/7) at the end - this will only work for queries returning exactly one field (like this one). If you need to fetch more fields or records, look at the [DatabaseStatementInterface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/interface/DatabaseStatementInterface/7) documentation.

Comment: Thanks a Lot, but it still gives me 2 very ugly warnings throughout the site when in the private messages the Sender (current user) has sent a message and the Recepient has not yet replied.

Warning: array_flip() [function.array-flip]: Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 178 of C:\wamp2\www\testsite7\includes\entity.inc).
    Warning: array_flip() [function.array-flip]: Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() (line 354 of C:\wamp2\www\testsite7\includes\entity.inc).

Comment: For more details about the problem that we are trying to solve please see this post http://drupal.org/node/1549540 and see if you can help us to get this working.

Comment: @drupalina - those error messages don't seem to be related to the query itself, and look like completely separate errors in the scope of your general problem/goal. As stackoverflow is about specific answers to specific questions, addressing them here is pretty much out of scope for your question of making the query work.

Comment: @drupalina - additionally, I can not even start to guess what might cause those errors from the code given here or in the linked drupal.org thread, apart from stating that it seems to be a pretty low level error within the entity system. You'd have to analyze your test system directly with a debugger, inspecting the $ids array passed into the EntityControlle::load() and cacheGet() functions for why they do not fit the expected format, and where they come from.

Comment: those errors appear only to Sender until the time that the Recepient replies.  In other words, due to this query uid is undetermined (we tell it to exclude us, the sender author, while the recepient has not yet authored his response), and that's what's causing these errors.  So we need to also tell it IF iud is none, then set uid to that of the Recepient.

Comment: @drupalina - again, specific answers for specific questions - the query works now (pure syntax problem), so your specific question is solved. What you have now is a different question, i.e. how to change the query (or surrounding code) to solve a different problem. This calls for a new question. (This is not meant to be rude - it is just one of stackoverflows goals to prevent 'endless threads' with ever changing scope.)

Comment: okey, thanks.  I'm new to StackOverflow, but I realise that each question is it's own.  The external links are there so as to provide a context to what this query is for.  Nevertheless, I'm still getting those two errors.